# Tableau: mapping fields in new datasource when field names are different in the new version

Tags: charts, datasource, tableau-api

I had some trouble previously when I wanted to take an existing visualization in tableau, and re-use it for a very similar data-set, but one where the field names are different.

In one case, as a workaround, I just renamed the new fields to the original field names even if the name didn't really apply. this allowed me to use the same chart I like. However, I wondered if there was a clean way to import a new data source and map the fields in the chart to the new field "titles" and preserve the chart?

I'm relatively new to tableau, so I'm sorry if this has been answered previously (I imagine it has somewhere). thanks

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a field in the data view pane and select "replace references"

This is essentially a replace-all feature. Usually, you would do this when a field in the data source no longer exists by the original name (and is shown with a red X). Rather than recreating all your views, if there is a new field that you can use instead, you can replace all references to the old field with the new one in one command.

You could also use custom SQL to specify field names, define a database view or rename fields as you suggest